# Java/OpenJDK, how to dynamically load library

Tags: java, java-module, modular-design

I want to make an application that can dynamically load java modules.

The problem is that MainApp must have all libraries used in modules.

For example i tried load module with external library and i cant run application without loading same library into MainApp.

Is there any way to load library dynamically into MainApp to preserve modularity of the application or any other solution for this problem?

Examples appreciated, thanks.

edit

Simple example

MainApp:

`List<ModuleInterface> listOfModules = ModuleInterface.getInstances();`

this list contains modules loaded using `ServiceLoader`

SampleModule:

```
public class DummyModule implements ModuleInterface{
    @Override
    public String doSomething() {
        //format gson for example
        return "Formated string";
    }
}
```

If i try in MainApp call `doSomething()` i can't because im missing gson library  in MainApp.

Comment: how is this related to javafx? looks like a plain java problem to me

Comment: javafx might be used as external library in modules, correct me if i'm wrong, i just need some help with this problem

Comment: When you say "library" do you mean a.) jar files, b.) modules or c.) native libraries (*.dll or *.so)?

Comment: You probably want a [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Comment: i added simple sample, i hope i made it clear now.